# Game «Life» on perl

Tags: массивы, процедуры, perl

Бесконечное поле (в данном случае тор(пончик)) (изначально рандомно) заполнено живыми и неживыми клетками(для простоты использовал 1 и 0 соответственно), если у живой клетки 2 или 3 соседа она выживает, в ост случаях погибает, если клетка мертвая и у нее 3 соседа то она воскресает.

Как узнать длину и ширину поля? Я писал на телефоне и там известна ширина и длина.
Где ошибка/и в процедуре sub neighbours?
Заранее спасибо!)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
$w=$ENV{LINES} //  35;
$h=$ENV{COLUMNS} // 53;

sub init# изначальное рандом поле( массив)
{
    for($i=0;$i<$h;$i++)
    {
        for($j=0;$j<$w;$j++)
        {
            $a[$j][$i]=int(rand()*2);
        }
    }
}

sub drawing#вывод массива
{
    for($i=0;$i<$h;$i++)
    {
        for($j=0;$j<$w;$j++)
        {
            print $a[$j][$i];
        }
    }
}

sub neighbours#подсчет соседей
{
    $j=<STDIN>;
    $i=<STDIN>;
    $x=$a[($j+1)%$w][($i+1)%$h]
    +$a[($j+1)%$w][$i] 
    +$a[$j][($i+1)%$h]
    +$a[($j-1)%$w][($i+1)%$h]
    +$a[($j+1)%$w][($i-1)%$h]
    +$a[($j-1)%$w][($i-1)%$h]
    +$a[($j-1)%$w][$i]
    +$a[$j][($i-1)%$h];
    return $x;
}

sub rules#делаем массив б из массива а по правилам
{
    for($j=0; $j<0;$j++)
    {
        if($a[$j][$i]==1 and(neighbours($j, $i)!=2 or neighbours($j,$i)!=3))
        {
            $b[$j][$i]=0;
        }
        elsif($a[$j][$i]==0 and neighbours($j,$i)=3)
        {
            $b[$j][$i]=1;
        }
        else
        {
            $b[$j][$i]=$a[$j][$i];
        }
    }
}

init;

while# можно поставить конечное кол-во раз
{
    drawing;
    rules;
    @a=@b;
}
```

## !/usr/bin/perl -w

my @field;

my $width;
my $height;

sub init
{
    $SIG{INT}=\&term;

```
$width=$ENV{COLUMNS} // 80;
$height=$ENV{LINES} // 25;

print "\e[?25l\e[2J";

for(my $y=0; $y<$height; $y++)
{
    for(my $x=0; $x<$width; $x++)
    {
        $field[$y][$x]=int rand 2;
    }
}
```

}

sub term
{
    print "\e[?25h\e[1;1H\e[0m\e[2JThank you!\n";
    exit;
}

sub step
{
    my @newField;
    for(my $y=0; $y<$height; $y++)
    {
        for(my $x=0; $x<$width; $x++)
        {
            my $neighbours=neighbours($x, $y);
            if($field[$y][$x])
            {
                $newField[$y][$x]
                    =($neighbours>=2 and $neighbours<=3)? 1: 0;
            }
            else
            {
                $newField[$y][$x]=($neighbours==3)? 1: 0;
            }
        }
    }
    @field=@newField;
}

sub neighbours
{
    my $x=shift;
    my $y=shift;
    return $field[$y][($x+1) % $width]
        +$field[($y+1) % $height][($x+1) % $width]
        +$field[($y+1) % $height][$x]
        +$field[($y+1) % $height][($x-1) % $width]
        +$field[$y][($x-1) % $width]
        +$field[($y-1) % $height][($x-1) % $width]
        +$field[($y-1) % $height][$x]
        +$field[($y-1) % $height][($x+1) % $width];
}

sub frame
{
    print "\e[1;1H";

```
for(my $y=0; $y<$height; $y++)
{
    my $y_=$y+1;
    for(my $x=0; $x<$width; $x++)
    {
        my $x_=$x+1;
        print "\e[$y_;${x_}H";
        print $field[$y][$x]? "\e[1;33m0": "\e[0;34mo";
    }
}
```

}

init;

while()
{
    frame;
    step;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sub neighbours( $j , $ i){  }
```

Так нельзя (в перле можно всё), нужно либо вообще без скобки с параметрами, либо почитать про [Прототипы](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes)

Comment: Спасибо, учту и сейчас почитаю :)

Comment: Ага. Ещё про то, что такое $ENV и как работать с хэшами, почему нельзя использовать переменные с именами $a и $b, почему первой строчкой должна быть "use strict", как работать с функциями... И объясние, что делают 2 первые строки в neighbours :-)

Comment: Первые 2 строки в neighbour.
По идее сама процедура по 2 координатам считает сколько живых соседей. Сейчас будет новая, полностью исправленная версия проги.

Comment: Так а что эти две строчки делают-то? Чинают что-то из STDIN? Нафига?

Comment: с клавиатуры вроде вводит значение..
саме проверьте, такой прогой 
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
$a=<STDIN>;
print $a;

Comment: Я вообще-то перл знаю :) Я спрашиваю что эти строчки делают в программе. В обоих случаях (передача значений при вызове neighbours и ручной ввод на каждой итерации) - это бред.

Answer (score 1):

Прежде чем изобретать очередной велосипед, хорошо бы ознакомиться с классическими решениями: [Game::Life - Plays Conway's Game of Life](http://search.cpan.org/~mneylon/Game-Life-0.04/Life.pm)

Comment: Именно мне сказали изобрести этот самый велосипед. Вы же изобретали сами хелло ворлд? Или ознокамливались с классическим решением?

Comment: Чтобы написать HW, нужно как минимум познакомиться с устройством программы вообще и системой ввода-вывода. А лучше всего это делается, имея рядом с документацией готовые работающие исходники. В любом случае код в посте - это вообще не перл. Невозможно искать ошибки в коде, который не запускается в принципе, и глючит в первых же строках:

    syntax error at 1.pl line 2, near "$ENV("
    syntax error at 1.pl line 3, near "$ENV("
    syntax error at 1.pl line 64, near "{"
    syntax error at 1.pl line 68, near "}"
    Execution of 1.pl aborted due to compilation errors.